# Changning value of int array to NaN in Python (ValueError)

Tags: python, numpy, nan

If I try:

```
ints = np.arange(10)
ints[0] = np.nan
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Is there a workaround here?
The solution I have so far is to convert the array to dtype=float like so:

```
casted = np.array(ints,dtype=float)
casted[0] = np.nan #  no errors
```

Comment: Integer types don't have a "NaN" value, only floating-point types do. The best way to solve your problem depends on what your problem *actually is*, which is to say, on *why* you want to store "NaN" values in the array.

Comment: Does the given answer solve your requirement now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

If a NAN array is needed then:

```
array = np.empty(3)
array[:] = np.NaN
```

or if you need to change a given value then:

```
ints = np.arange(10).astype(float)
ints[0]=np.NAN
pdintseries=pd.Series(int).astype(dtype='Int64') #pandas has released support for nan containing Int64 dtypes.
```

[na support pd series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)

You can further convert the series to numpy object.

**or directly:**

```
int=np.arange(10).astype(object)
int[0]=np.NAN
```

Doesn't specifically solve your problem, but some way out here.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you actual problem is but I has a simlar issue where I wanted to set a value to `NaN` if the value was an "error mesurement". What I instead did was to generate a "Correct index" list where all of the non-error elements where indicated with respective index:

```
# A sensor could measure distance and angle
non_error = np.where(distance != 4294967295) # 4294967295 indicates an error
non_error_angle = angle[non_error]
non_error_distance = distance[non_error]
```

In the actual implementation I had multiple arrays of data that all had the same error index so the `non_error` list could be used to find the non-error elements in all of the arrays without any risk of messing up the order of the data since they corresponded with index.